# Magento2 - why header& footer is missing from checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout

Can anyone tell why **header** & **footer** is missing from **checkout page**.

I have searched this on google, but didn't find anything useful except some folks saying that- For **user experience, its not there.**

Comment: it's default Magento function. You need to display it?

Comment: They are not loaded to complete the order simply and quickly, this is the default Magento as [S H Patel](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/31609/s-h-patel) said.

Comment: Yes it's default Magento.

Answer (score 1):

Is a default magento funcitonality.

To add the footer and the header on checkout page you need to overrite:**\Magento_Checkout\layout\checkout_index_index.xml**

by adding this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false" />           
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/> 
        <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/>     
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

By default it is disabled in luma/blank theme. you just need to create basic structure on your theme folder and re-add the blocks you want.

path: `yourthemename\Magento_Checkout\layout\override\theme\Magento\blank`

just copy `checkout_index_index.xml` here and in this file paste the below code

Please set remove="false" instead of commenting that line.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
      <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false" />
      <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
      <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false" />
      <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="false" />
      <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
      <referenceContainer name="footer-container"  remove="false"/>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: It is not working. Showing error. 

Are you sure about this path? -> yourthemename\Magento_Checkout\layout\override\theme\Magento\blank